# How can I change color of buttons on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of button like this:

```css
button {
        background-color: rgb(0, 174, 255);
        color: rgb(227, 72, 20);
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        font-size: 10px;
        margin-top: 85px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        border-color: rgb(189, 227, 20);
        z-index: 20;
    }
```

```html
<button class = "btn" id = "tp1" onclick="testpoint1()">TP1</button>
<button class = "btn" id = "tp2" onclick="testpoint2()">TP2</button>
<button class = "btn" id = "tp3" onclick="testpoint3()">TP3</button>
<button class = "btn" id = "tp3" onclick="testpoint4()">TP4</button>
```

At first, all buttons have the same color (color A). Then, when I click a button (e.g. TP1, its background color change to another color (color B). And when I click on another button (TP2), its color will change to B and the color of TP1 will change to its original color (color A)
How can I do that with Javascripts.

Comment: what you are describing is a checkbox and your don't need JS to do it. There is a native element for this

Comment: @Temani Afif That would be a radio box no?

Answer (score 1):

Check the below code snippet

```js
function testpoint(evt) {
  const id = evt.target.id;
  const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
  for(let itr=0; itr<buttons.length; itr++) {
    buttons[itr].classList.remove('btn');
  }
  const targetBtn = document.getElementById(id);
  targetBtn.classList.add('btn');
}
```

```css
button {
        background-color: rgb(0, 174, 255);
        color: rgb(227, 72, 20);
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        font-size: 10px;
        margin-top: 85px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        border-color: rgb(189, 227, 20);
        z-index: 20;
    }
.btn {
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button id = "tp1" onclick="testpoint(event)">TP1</button>
<button id = "tp2" onclick="testpoint(event)">TP2</button>
<button id = "tp3" onclick="testpoint(event)">TP3</button>
<button id = "tp4" onclick="testpoint(event)">TP4</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll show the answer that you want.
The result is correct.
If you have some problem, send the message.

```css
button {
    background-color: rgb(0, 174, 255);
    color: rgb(227, 72, 20);
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-top: 85px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-color: rgb(189, 227, 20);
    z-index: 20;
}

.active {
    background: orange;
    color: white;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body id="body">
    <button class = "btn" id = "tp1">TP1</button>
    <button class = "btn" id = "tp2">TP2</button>
    <button class = "btn" id = "tp3">TP3</button>
    <button class = "btn" id = "tp3">TP4</button>
    <script>
        var header = document.getElementById("body");
        var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");
        for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
            btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
            if (current.length > 0) { 
                current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            this.className += " active";
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. It’s perfectly suit to my situation

Answer (score -2):

If you are fine with using jQuery you could do it like this. We assign a click listener to every element with the class `btn`, which removes the class from every `btn` and adds it to the specific element clicked afterwards.

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  $(".btn").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
button {
  background-color: rgb(0, 174, 255);
  color: rgb(227, 72, 20);
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-top: 85px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-color: rgb(189, 227, 20);
  z-index: 20;
}

.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" id="tp1">TP1</button>
<button class="btn" id="tp2">TP2</button>
<button class="btn" id="tp3">TP3</button>
<button class="btn" id="tp3">TP4</button>
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar to jQuery. Thus, I rewrite it into pure javascripts like this:
 document.querySelector(".btn").click(function() {
    document.querySelector(".btn").classList.remove("active");
    document.querySelector(this).classList.add("active");
});
Unfortunately, nothing happened.

Comment: @LêHuyThanh check if my answer works for you

Comment: @Amaarockz, I’ve onclick to execute another function, so I don’t want to make that function more complicated

Comment: what I say is you have a common function and based on the id name that you get through event, implement the logic or call modular function using if conditioning